# OpenCV real-time object tracking

Tags: camera, opencv

I've been playing around with my Raspberry Pi model 3 including the camera v2. 
I've managed to install opencv Python and run some code such as detecting various objects or properties of different images.

However, I'm interested in using a *Python* script to do real time object tracking with the camera module.

If someone could please send or refer me to source code which works with these features:

1. OpenCV Python on Raspberry Pi 3
2. Camera module v2
3. Real time video capture on the GUI of the Pi

Answer (score -1):

There is a great PI blog called PyImageSearch with many PI app developers and a strong engagement level (comment section). Adrian has a background in Computer Vision and shares all his code. I have learned a lot from him regarding the PI, Computer Vision and now some Deep Learning on the PI. Hope to see on the blog...

https://www.pyimagesearch.com/2017/10/16/raspberry-pi-deep-learning-object-detection-with-opencv/

https://www.pyimagesearch.com

Thanks,
Kas

[image]

Comment: In keeping with [our policy regarding informationless link-only answers](http://meta.raspberrypi.stackexchange.com/q/842/5538), if this post is not edited to contain information that can stand as an answer, however minimal, in 48 hours it will be converted to Community Wiki to simplify having it corrected by the community.

Comment: updated for python